# Deploying all roles present in roles folder

Tags: ansible

My directory structure looks like this:

```
ls -tlrh
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel     5B 17 May 09:50 playbook.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  wheel    64B 17 May 09:50 roles
```

The roles folder contains a number of roles defined properly.

My current playbook looks like :

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - common
    - webservers
    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
    .
    .
    .
    - appN
```

Now my issue is every time I add a new role to the `roles/` folder, I have to add it to my `playbook.yml` file **manually**.

Is there a way that I can tell ansible to basically install ALL roles present in the `roles/` folder?

Answer (score 0):

While I think that is a bad idea, I was curious if it was in fact possible, and the answer seems to be yes:

```
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
  - delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: yes
    set_fact:
      role_list: '["{{ lookup("pipe", "/bin/ls -1 roles") | replace(newline, sep) }}"]'
    vars:
      newline: "\n"
      sep: '", "'
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: '{{ item }}'
    with_items: '{{ role_list }}'
```

I was expecting the [`fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html) lookup to make that trivial, but it only does single children *files*, not directories

A "production grade" version of that might use `find roles -type d -maxdepth 0` or similar sanity checking to avoid grabbing something that ended up in the `roles` directory without actually being a role, but that goes back to the "I think that's a bad idea" part

Similarly implied in your question is that all the roles are applied according to their sort order, which is either going to end up naming roles `01_do_it_first` and `05_do_it` but q.v. "fraught with peril"